# Can an indigent defendant pay for a lawyer of choice using any of the following financial arrangements?

Tags: united-states, attorney-fees

An indigent person is accused of a serious crime. S/he knows, and would like to hire a well known defense lawyer (think Perry Mason) but is broke.

An indigent defendant will be assigned a public defender at public expense. "Perry Mason" is unwilling to defend the defendant for "nothing," but will accept the case at the standard "public defender" rates, which are much less than he normally charges. Can the defendant then redirect the "public defender" fees to "Perry Mason?"

Can "Perry Mason" structure a contingency arrangement with a small up front fee and a large contingency fee for acquittal? (The defendant is charged with murder, will inherit a lot of money if acquitted, but not if convicted.)